# Firewall rejecting UDP "connections"?

Tags: iptables, udp, shorewall, conntrack

I have a server that is aggregating logs from various other servers. It mostly works great, however from time-to-time (right after a reboot, but not all reboots) it will decide that various UDP "connections" are in some weird state, and reject incoming packets.

Thing is, that doesn't make sense, because there are no "connections" when dealing with UDP!

Here's an example of what shows up in my firewall logs:

```
Shorewall:loc2fw:REJECT:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=/*snip*/ SRC=10.x.x.4 DST=10.y.y.14 LEN=159 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=254 ID=37407 PROTO=UDP SPT=514 DPT=514 LEN=139
```

After running the command `sudo conntrack -D -p udp` to clear all UDP "connections" from conntrack, here's a log showing an incoming message from the same host:

```
Shorewall:loc_dnat:REDIRECT:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=/*snip*/ SRC=10.x.x.4 DST=10.y.y.14 LEN=201 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=254 ID=50542 PROTO=UDP SPT=514 DPT=514 LEN=181
```

And here's what shows up in conntrack for this host before I ran the `-D` command:

```
udp      17 29 src=10.x.x.4 dst=10.y.y.14 sport=514 dport=514 [UNREPLIED] src=10.y.y.14 dst=10.x.x.4 sport=514 dport=514 mark=0 use=1
```

Here's the relevant bits from my Shorewall configuration for this port:

```
#ACTION         SOURCE          DEST            PROTO   DPT
SECTION NEW
REDIRECT:info   loc             5000            tcp,udp 514
ACCEPT:info     loc             $FW             tcp,udp 5000
```

And for completeness' sake, here's the resultant chain in iptables (this is after the `conntrack -D -p udp` command was run and the firewall had been properly accepting packets for a while):

```
Chain loc2fw (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
16328 1648K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 6428  386K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 /* Ping */
    1    64 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 /* SSH */
   18  1080 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 /* HTTP */
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000 ctorigdstport 514
  12M 6677M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5000 ctorigdstport 514
    0     0 ~log0      tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]  tcp dpt:5000
    0     0 ~log0      udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]  udp dpt:5000
   52  3088 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9200
 126M   32G Reject     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 126M   32G LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "Shorewall:loc2fw:REJECT:"
 126M   32G reject     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
```

As you can see, I'm using a REDIRECT rule to accept connections coming in on port 514 and send them instead to port 5000, where my log aggregator listens (was easier to accomplish this in the firewall than to jump through the hoops to allow an unprivileged user to open a privileged port).

I can't understand why UDP "connections" seem to get into this strange state where they get rejected by the default policy; I say this because they show up quite clearly in conntrack, and deleting them from there seems to "reset" everything and let the messages flow into my log aggregator again. At this point the only alternative I see is setting up cron to run my `conntrack` command shortly after reboot, but I'd much rather understand *why* this is happening and fix the cause rather than just implement this workaround.